# posix matching expression with operators

Tags: posix

I have this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
a=$(command -v rofi)

[[ $a == *rofi ]] && echo foo
```

what would be the last line in posix with dash shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use globbing with a `case` statement:

```
#!/bin/sh
a=$(command -v rofi)
case $a in
  (*rofi) printf 'foo\n';;
  (*)     printf 'does not match\n';;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'll accept a non-shell option, you can use `expr` with a POSIX basic regular expression (the same kind accepted by `grep` and `sed` by default):

```
a=$(command -v rofi)

# expr STRING : REGEXP
expr "$a" : '.*rofi$' >/dev/null && echo foo
```